# I want to remove duplicate values from an array a and get the new arrary b as answer. But array b is containing all the values of array a

Tags: php

I want to remove duplicate values from array a and get a new array b without duplicate values. What  am doing wrong. HELP!!!

```
<?php
 $a = array('pasta','vegetables','vegetables','salad','salad');
 $b=array();

   for ($i=0;$i<=count($a);$i++){

     if(!in_array($b,$a[$i])){

      array_push($b,$a[$i]);    
    }
 }
 print_r($b);

?>
```

Comment: try array_unique function

Comment: could use it but my senior told me not to use that function.

Answer (score 1):

> You should try this

```
     $a = array('pasta','vegetables','vegetables','salad','salad');
     echo '<pre>';
     echo 'Array A <br>';
     print_r($a);
     echo '<br> After removing duplicate value  array B<br>';
     $b=array_unique($a);
     print_r($b);
```

[image: Output :-]

Answer (score 0):

In your code you need to make 2 changes...

1) run the for loop for `$i<count($a)` not `$i<=count($a)` because you start `$i` with zero so you need to run the for loop for one counter less than `count($a)`

2) It will `if(!in_array($a[$i], $b))` instead of `if(!in_array($b,$a[$i]))` because you need to find element of `$a` array to be already pushed in new array `$b` or not

So your code will be :

```
<?php

 $a = array('pasta','vegetables','vegetables','salad','salad');
 $b=array();

   for ($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){

     if(!in_array($a[$i], $b)){

      array_push($b,$a[$i]);    
    }
 }
 print_r($b);
?>
```

Let me know if anything wrong in my answer or you need any more clarification... Good luck!